# Upload file to remote server

Tags: linux, bash, file-upload, ftp

Have a problem. I need to upload file to remote ftp server using linux bash..
smth like this: `cp file.tar.gz ftp://username:password@host/file.tar.gz`
Can it be done?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I would use http://www.ncftp.com/ for this.

//see comment =>
"Specifically, take a look at ncftpput."

Comment: Specifically, take a look at [ncftpput](http://www.ncftpd.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html).

Comment: Yeah.. working like a charm. `ncftpput -b -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD HOST /upload_folder/ /full/path/to/uploading/file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use just plain ftp + bash for this.

Bash script begin:

echo "put $1" > commands.txt;

echo "quit" >> commands.txt;

ftp user@ftp://username:password@host  < commands.txt

Bash script end.

Put that in ftp.sh. run it like ./ftp.sh file.tar.gz. this will upload to the ftp server.